# How to use gparted to allocate unallocated space from VBox dynamic drive

Tags: virtualbox, gparted, partitioning

I'm using VirtualBox with a Ubuntu 16.04 VM on OS X High Sierra. I increased the size of my dynamic storage and rebooted the VM using a live ISO and ran `gparted`.

```
gparted output
```

[image]

The two partitions that offer resizing when right-clicked are `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda5`, but with neither is the space available equal to the unallocated space... they are as follows:

[image: sda5]
[image: sda1]

How do I make use of the 40G unallocated space? One answer (1054352) says to first increase the size of the extended partition first, but mine (`sda2`) doesn't have that option.

When I follow Curtis's answer, doing the gparted and then a mount:

```
# df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        601M  8.6M  592M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   18G   12G  4.9G  71% /
tmpfs                        3.0G  6.7M  3.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2                    90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop3                    92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop1                   264M  264M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/90
/dev/loop0                    91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/sda1                    472M  463M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                        601M   44K  601M   1% /run/user/1000
```

which looks like the 20G partition is mounted, but when I try:

```
apt-get install byobu 

gzip: stdout: No space left on device. update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-43-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason the partition cannot be resized is because it is active.

To increase the size of the */dev/sda5* LVM2 PV logical partition:

1. Select the */dev/sda5* LMV2 PV logical partition and Deactivate it with the menu option **Partition > Deactivate**.
2. Select the */dev/sda2* extended partition and use **Partition > Resize/Move** to grow the partition to use the unallocated space.
3. **Edit > Apply all operations**.
4. Select the */dev/sda5* LVM2 PV logical partitition and use **Partition > Resize/Move** to grow the partition to use the unallocated space within the extended partition.
5. **Edit > Apply all operations**.
6. Open an terminal prompt and use commands such as `lvresize` to grow the LVM Logical Volume which you would like to be larger, such as the one containing the Root Volume Group.

I recommend learning more about [Logical Volume Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) by reading a tutorial or two from the Internet.

'Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. The gparted steps worked fine. I did read (more), and went one of the recommended routes of using mount at the end, which shows the partition mounted now but doesn’t seem to use it (details added, above).

Comment: I’ll make the mount a separate question.

Comment: Now that you've increased the partition size and the LVM2 Physical Volume, you will also need to grow the LVM2 Logical Volume containing your file system with a command like `lvresize`. Next you will need to grow the file system.  If it is ext4 you would use a command like `resize2fs`.